# Passing Object and its Methods to another function

Tags: reactjs

I have a npm library that I import into my app, see below:

```
import Chess from 'chess.js';

let chess = new Chess();
```

There is a method shown in the following link that uses `chess.moves()`:

https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md

The above two lines of code are in my file App.js. I have a utilities.js file where I want to put a function, called from my function inside of App.js. However, I want to be able to use `chess.moves()` within my function inside utilities.js.

How can I use the `chess.moves()` inside of utilities.js?

Comment: Pass `chess` as a variable to your function(s) inside of utilities.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does passing chess object in your imported function work for you?

In your utitilies.js

```
let myNewFunction = (chess)=>{
chess.moves();
}

export myNewFunction;
```

In your app.js

```
import Chess from 'chess.js';
import {myNewFunction } from './utilities';


let chess = new Chess();
....

myNewFunction(chess);
....
```

Comment: I gave a slightly simplified version. In my actual app, it goes like this: App.js calls function in piece.js, where a function calls utilities.js. I gave a simplified version so I could get the idea. But perhaps it makes a difference that an object is passed to another function, and then I have to pass it to a third?

Comment: No it does not make a difference. Unless you call new Chess() at some poont, it is the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I have found that the function was called 3 times, but only one of those functions passed the chess object, hence the error I was getting. I got it working now. :)